# Xcode 8 debugger is showing less characters in output

Tags: xcode, debugging

I recently moved to Xcode 8 (8A218a). I am finding that when I print any very long strings (using NSLog) into the console, it's not showing them in full. There looks like some sort of character limit? Does anyone know how to resolve this, please?

This was working before.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like an iOS issue, rather than Xcode/lldb issue.

1. The messages are good on the Simulator.
2. On a real iOS 10 device, I just opened Device Logs (from Xcode main menu: Window > Devices > <kbd>View Device Logs</kbd>) where I can see a huge number of messages and crash dumps being cut the same way.

I believe they'll remove that limit as soon as iOS becomes more stable (i.e. system processes don't crash every few seconds).